# sudo -u ... -i doesn't preserve a user's PATH

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I'm trying to determine a user's path when I'm root, but sudo, even with the -i flag, doesn't seem to replicate the user's environment correctly. Is this some sudoers policy setting?

```
$ sudo bash
# export PATH=$PATH:/dev/null/$RANDOM
# printenv PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/dev/null/28718
# sudo -u david-ehrmann -i printenv PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/dev/null/28718
#
```

Comment: As you suspect sudoers Why don't you check the [man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html)?

Comment: env_reset seems to be set, but the man page isn't clear on whether or not it overrides -i

Answer (score 2):

From `man sudoers`

> As a special case, if sudo's -i option (initial login) is specified, sudoers will initialize the environment regardless of the value of env_reset.  The DISPLAY, PATH and TERM variables remain unchanged; HOME, MAIL, SHELL, USER, and LOGNAME are set based on the target user.

Thus, `-i` means that you get to keep your `$PATH` unless the user's `.bash_profile` (or similar, depending on shell) changes `$PATH` itself.

What's not clear is whether `secure_path` overrides this behavior of `-i`.  I believe it should (plus changes by the user's login scripts).